# Wordpress serious meta bug

Tags: wordpress, facebook, meta

I have a wordpress site and until few days ago everything was fine, but now when you share an article on facebook, at the beginning of the og:description and the twitter:description, there is a text saying:

**"Want create site? Find Free WordPress Themes and plugins".**

When I check the website source code in browser, there is no such text. Facebook debugger sees it as well. I found a pretty lot of websites on the internet with the same issua but no answer. I tried deactivating the 2 new plugin but it solved nothing. Anybody met this problem before? I would really appreciate any help.

My website is in hungarian: https://www.noidivat.hu

Comment: I just tested your homepage and an article on Facebook debugger and there is no such text. On which pages are you seeing it?

Comment: Hi, for example: https://www.noidivat.hu/2017/03/04/narancs-finom-de-nem-borunkon/

I installed an og plugin and reindexed some page, it solves it manually but still have no clue what is the source of this problem.

Comment: Could it be that your website is hacked? Can you try and find that string on the server?

Comment: Are you using "Media Grid Plugin"?

Comment: I am not using Media Grid Plugin. Maybe the server is hacked but I cannot find it anywhere. True, I am not an expert in finding strings on server but the source code of the website is clean

Comment: Code could be obfuscated so it can't be found by plain text search. As far as I can see your website doesn't have this issue anymore so it is possible that you already removed it along with some plugin or with WordPress update.